# listing a data got from a query laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I'm making a simple web application using laravel platform

I have two models `Section` and `Company` every section contains some companies
i need to view all the sections and on clicking on one of them it shows it's companies by passing the id of section in the url

that's my view

```
    @foreach($companies as $company)    
            {{($company->description)}}
            {{$company->name}}
            @endforeach

@foreach ($sections as $section)
        <li><a href="portfolio?id={{$section->id}}">{{$section->name}}</a></li>
        @endforeach


        {{$id}}
```

and this is my controller function

```
public function getIndex()
    {
        $companies= Company::where('section_id' , '=' , Input::get('id'));

        return View::make('portfolio.test')
        ->with('sections' , Section::all())
        ->with('companies' , $companies)
        ->with('id' , Input::get('id'));

    }
```

I used `{{id}}` to make sure that the id is read correctly .. 
and tested the query by `dd($companies)` and it dump values

it shows the sections and the id correctly .. but it did not list the companies in the view !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're still only building the query when you get the companies - you haven't actually gotten them from the database yet. Just add a `get()` call (see below) and you should be good to go, assuming the rest is correct.

```
$companies = Company::where('section_id' , '=' , Input::get('id'))->get();
```